# Creating Dynamic octopusdpeloy relese via github actions

Tags: github-actions, octopus-deploy

I get the below error when i try to create a release dynamically with octopusdpeloy via github actions

Action code

```
  - name: Create a release in Octopus Deploy 
      uses: OctopusDeploy/create-release-action@v2
      env:
          OCTOPUS_API_KEY: ${{ inputs.OCTOPUS_APIKEY }} 
          OCTOPUS_HOST: "https://octopusdev.fidev.com/"
      with:
          project: ${{ github.event.repository.name }}
          packages: {Deployartifact}:{${{ steps.deploy_setup.outputs.JFROG_VERSION }}}
```

```
Run OctopusDeploy/install-octopus-cli-action@v1
Latest version available: 9.1.7
✓ Octopus CLI version found: 9.1.7
⬇️ Downloading Octopus CLI 9.1.7...
 Extracting Octopus CLI 9.1.7...
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -Sta -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop' ; try { Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem } catch { } ; if ((Get-Command -Name Expand-Archive -Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive -ErrorAction Ignore)) { Expand-Archive -LiteralPath 'E:\actions-runner\workspace\_temp\2712f7bc-357a-4509-93d3-2318c71651bd.zip' -DestinationPath 'E:\actions-runner\workspace\_temp\86a0af86-765f-4e8f-9e13-9a642c6bd7f2' -Force } else {[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('E:\actions-runner\workspace\_temp\2712f7bc-357a-4509-93d3-2318c71651bd.zip', 'E:\actions-runner\workspace\_temp\86a0af86-765f-4e8f-9e13-9a642c6bd7f2', $true) }"
 Octopus CLI 9.1.7 installed successfully
Run OctopusDeploy/create-release-action@v2
The package argument 'Deployartifact:' does not use expected format of : {Step Name}:{Version}
Exit code: -1
Error: Error: The process 'E:\actions-runner\workspace\_tool\octo\9.1.7\x64\octo.exe' failed with exit code 4294967295
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your packages line to be:

`packages: Deployartifact:${{ steps.deploy_setup.outputs.JFROG_VERSION }}`

The packages reference does not need the extra braces, just use either `PackageID:version` or `StepName:PackageId:Version`.

Comment: i get The version portion of the package constraint 'DEPLOY:1.0.0.47.28653d0' is not a valid semantic version number octopusdeploy

Comment: The version number in dotted notation must be all numeric values. Your 4th value contains a `d`. If you wish to use non-numeric values you can use prerelease tags using the `-prereleaseTag` format. See https://semver.org/ for more details